# How to check Ubuntu crash log in last session?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, crash, logging

My headless Ubuntu (11.10) crashed. When I plug in keyboard and monitor, I see an non-interactive cursor (no blink) on a black screen. SSh, telnet don't work from other machines. Ping works.

I have restarted the machine. How could I check the log files of the last session, so I can know more about this crash?

Comment: Look in `/var/log`

Comment: They are for this session right? I already restarted the box. What are the file name patterns for the last session's logs?

Comment: The ones that ends in .1 are from the last syslog session. A quick `ls -lta /var/log` will give you an idea of which files are new.

Comment: I discovered those files:

alternatives.log.1  daemon.log.1  dpkg.log.1    kern.log.1  messages.1          syslog.1
auth.log.1          debug.1       jockey.log.1  lpr.log.1   pm-powersave.log.1  user.log.1
.

messages.1 is the biggest file. So I assume it is the file that most likely has the information I need.

Answer (score 14):

On Ubuntu (running 13.10 as of this day), the /var/log/apport.log contains crash log messages, which is rotated per configuration in /etc/logrotate.d/apport. The actual crash reports are saved in /var/crash/ -- Not sure how relevant this information is with regard to other releases. Also, this may only be true with apport enabled (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Apport#How_to_enable_apport).